System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
At the moment I am trying to use VB6 (.dll) file in a .NET environment, but I am running against an error what I cannot resolve.
Error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {7A96757E-32E3-456E-9724-8D561B43BB7D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Code:
Guid clsid = new Guid("7A96757E-32E3-456E-9724-8D561B43BB7D");
Type objType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsid);
dynamic comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);

Location of the VB6 (.dll) file: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\ {7A96757E-32E3-456E-9724-8D561B43BB7D}
Platform target in Visual Studio 2019: x86
Enable 32-Bit Applications in IIS: True

CLSID{7A96757E-32E3-456E-9724-8D561B43BB7D} is invalid, are you sure it's not CLSID\{7A96757E-32E3-456E-9724-8D561B43BB7D} as the clsid should be a key

Sorry, I missed that stackoverflow had removed the \ @SimonMourier

80040154 really means the class is not registered, ie: underlying COM calls don't see anything for that clsid in the registry used by the client. Are you 100% sure your client is running as x86? Does it work outside of IIS? You can use procmon to check registry access https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

I'm really sure that my client is running as x86. And no it doens't work outside of IIS.
When I try to search the GUID in procmon I get the following response: Cannot find string 7A96757E-32E3-456E-9724-8D561B43BB7D

So your component is not registered

Register the VB6 DLL with RegSvr32 (use the one located in %Windows%\SysWOW64). Which is btw exactly what the error message says: "Class not registered"

I tried to register it again with: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 "C:\R4_7_x_stage_5\Output\Bin\LotTrackServer.dll". I can find the component in the register where I expect the component. After I'm importing the .dll file in Visual Studio 2019 with tlbimp "C:\R4_7_x_stage_5\Output\Bin\LotTrackServer.dll" /tlbreference:"C:\R4_7_x_stage_5\Output\Bin\SessionInterface.tlb" /tlbreference:"C:\R4_7_x_stage_5\Output\System32\stdole2.tlb" /tlbreference:"C:\R4_7_x_stage_5\Output\System32\msvbvm60.dll" /out:LotTrackServer.dll. I still get the same error and can't find it with procmon

If you don't get any error when calling regsvr32 on your dll but nothing is registered in the registry, it means what the dll registration code does doesn't really work (PS: make sure you run it as admin). PS: #import 'ing a tlb with visual studio is irrelevant to registration.
